# Calculating the 4 weekly totals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, rolling-computation

I have a dataset where Week Ending column is showing the latest date for that week, and the measures are total for that week. The dates are weekly, and goes back to 2019.

```
Week Ending Category    Segment               Timestamp  Units  Sterling
01/01/2022  FRAGRANCES  ANCILLARIES         1 Week    2   3
01/01/2022  FRAGRANCES  GIFT SETS           1 Week    3   4
01/01/2022  FRAGRANCES  TOTAL JUICES            1 Week    5   4
01/01/2022  MAKEUP          ALL OTHER           1 Week    2   3
01/01/2022  MAKEUP  MAKEUP TOTAL EYE            1 Week    1   2
01/01/2022  MAKEUP  MAKEUP TOTAL FACE           1 Week    4   6
01/01/2022  MAKEUP  MAKEUP TOTAL LIP            1 Week    3   2
```

I am trying to add rows for a 4 Week Rolling calculation, where for every date it will calculate the total of 4 weeks for every category and segment.

I tried below code but the totals are not what they are supposed to be. Can you help me?

```
# create a new DataFrame with the rolling 4-week sum data
new_df = df.copy()
rolling_sum = new_df.groupby(['Week Ending','Category', 'Segment','Timestamp' ]).sum().rolling(window=4, min_periods=4).sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: show the expected result